# Monotouch Dialog get element value in delegate

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a rootelement created from dynamic object. I want to get the object Id when I tapped an element:

```
var section = new Section("","Select a complex and then a property");
var root = new RootElement("Complexes"){section};

foreach(Complex complex in complexes){

    var line = new RootElement(complex.Name);

    foreach(Property property in complex.Properties){

        line.Add(new Section(property.Name,"Select the property to work"){

            new StringElement(property.Description, delegate {

                // NEED HELP HERE!!! here I want to get property.Id

            })
        });
    }
    section.Add(line);
}

this.Root = root;
```

Any clue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy property.Id in local variable and use in delegate

```
var line = new RootElement(complex.Name);

foreach(Property property in complex.Properties){

    var propertyId = property.Id;

    line.Add(new Section(property.Name,"Select the property to work"){

        new StringElement(property.Description, delegate {

            (new UIAlertView("title", "Id - " + propertyId, null, "Ok")).Show();

        })
    });
}
section.Add(line);
```